# 400 Client Error: Web Environment' is not a valid choice for this field for url: https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/

Tags: python, packaging, pypi, python-packaging, twine

When i put my module on the package when uploading to pypi, something went wrong and I did not know how to fix it

```
$ twine upload dist/*
Uploading distributions to https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
Uploading zaoshu-0.1.1-py3-none-any.whl

HTTPError: 400 Client Error: classifiers: 'Development Status :: 4 - 
BetaEnvironment :: Web Environment' is not a valid choice for this 
field for url: https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
```

my setup.py

```
setup(
    name="zaoshu",
    version="0.1.1",
    author="Wei Cheng",
    author_email="*****@zaoshu.io",
    description="zaoshu包实现里对造数openapi功能的封装，提高开发效率.",
    long_description=open("README.md").read(),
    license="MIT",
    url="https://github.com/zaoshu/pysdk",
    packages=['zaoshu'],
    install_requires=[
        "requests",
    ],
    python_requires = '> = 3',
    classifiers=[
        "Development Status :: 4 - Beta"
        "Environment :: Web Environment",
        "Intended Audience :: Developers",
        "License :: Free For Home Use",
        "Natural Language :: Chinese (Simplified)",
        "Programming Language :: Python",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.0",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.1",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.2",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.3",

    ],
)
```

my .pypirc

```
[distutils] 
index-servers  =
pypi 

[pypi] 
username = your_username 
password = your_password
```

Above is my code, we help look at the reasons

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a comma after the 1st classifier:

```
classifiers=[
        "Development Status :: 4 - Beta", <<<=== Here!
```

Without the comma Python concatenates the strings:

```
classifiers=[
    "Development Status :: 4 - BetaEnvironment :: Web Environment",
```

Well-known Python misfeature. :-(